# OnResponse is not getting called in retrofit xml parsing

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I am new to retrofit **xml parsing** and following a tutorial for **xml parsing**. But the result is not showing, after debugging it I found that `onresponse` is not getting called.

I am trying to figure out via `onFailure`, but getting an error as can not construct inner class.

Here is the interface

```
public interface MapAPI {
    @GET("/dealer")
    Call<ApiResponse> getList(@Query("zip") String zip);
}
```

Here is the API response class.

```
@Root(name = "dealers", strict = false)
public class ApiResponse {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    public List<Dealer> dealerList;

    @Root(name = "dealer")
    public class Dealer {
        @Element(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Element(name = "google_static_map_url")
        private String staticMapUrl;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getStaticMapUrl() {
            return staticMapUrl;
        }

        public void setStaticMapUrl(String staticMapUrl) {
            this.staticMapUrl = staticMapUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Code of `activity`

```
private void getDealerList() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).client(new OkHttpClient()).addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()).build();
    MapAPI dealerApiKey = retrofit.create(MapAPI.class);

    Call<ApiResponse> callResponse = dealerApiKey.getList("55082");
    callResponse.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> mResponse) {

            mDealerList = mResponse.body().dealerList;
            ArrayList<Dealer> dealerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(mDealerList);
            adapter = new StoreListAdapter(dealerArrayList, getApplicationContext());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Check the error implementing `onFailure` method

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I have done this  public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getLocalizedMessage());
            } how to check the message??

Comment: Try with `t.getMessage`, or place a breakpoint and read the attributes

Comment: yes i have done that and getting error message is Can not construct inner class com.simpalm.blanco.Retrofit.ApiResponse$Dealer, @JuanCruzSoler

Comment: please check my updated ApiResponse.Java

Comment: Place `public class Dealer` in a separate file

Comment: Previously i had , but i was getting error, let me try again

Comment: Element 'name' does not have a match in class com.simpalm.blanco.model.Dealer at line 4 @JuanCruzSoler, i have tried all solutions in SO but :( no luck